# ten cheapest room for each city

Tags: mysql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

I have 3 table Room, Hotel, City, how can i select ten cheapest room  and its hotel_id for each city
possible to execute the subquery for each city?

```
SELECT price, room_id, hotel_id, city_id
    FROM Hotel 
    JOIN  Room USING(hotel_id)
ORDER BY price
LIMIT 10


Scheme
CREATE TABLE `City` (
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`city_id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Hotel` (
  `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `hotel_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`hotel_id`),
   CONSTRAINT `Hotel_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`city_id`) REFERENCES `City` (`city_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)

CREATE TABLE `Room` (
  `room_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `hotel_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `room_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `room_price1` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`room_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Room_FK_1` FOREIGN KEY (`hotel_id`) REFERENCES `Hotel` (`hotel_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
)
```

query with subquery

```
SELECT 
     r.room_price1, r.room_id, h.hotel_name, c.city_name
FROM Hotel h 
INNER JOIN Room r ON
    h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
INNER JOIN City c USING(city_id)
WHERE (
   SELECT count(*) from Room as rt
   JOIN Hotel ht using(hotel_id)
   where c.city_id = ht.city_id and rt.room_price1 < r.room_price1 OR (rt.room_price1 = r.room_price1 AND rt.room_id < r.room_id)
) < 3 
ORDER BY c.city_name, h.hotel_id, r.room_price1
```

if some hotels have some room_price1 this query return more then 3 row for city and i need 3 unique hotel per city this query can return 3 room from one hotel

ill try use user vars

```
set @num := 0, @type := '';
select *
from (
   select r.room_price1 pr, r.room_id, h.hotel_name, c.city_name,
      @num := if(@type = city_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @type := city_id as dummy
  from Hotel h
  JOIN Room r USING(hotel_id)
  INNER JOIN City c USING(city_id)
  order by city_name, r.room_price1 asc
) as x where x.row_number <=3;
```

this method return wrong sort for row_number < 6 (my init data)

Comment: maybe you can describe the schema for _hotel_ _room_ and _City_?

Comment: Is this actually homework as Kynth has assumed? That will affect my answer as the best way of doing it in MySQL is to use user variables but homework probably wants you to use a sub query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there a ton of different blog post about this topic out there.

The most valuable for me, possibly was

Xaprb post (see section "Select the top N rows from each group" for a detailed explaination)

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

In your case that would mean. Modelling this SQL to your needs.

```
select type, variety, price
from fruits
where (
   select count(*) from fruits as f
   where f.type = fruits.type and f.price < fruits.price
) <= 2;
```

lets try it out

```
SELECT 
   r.price, r.room_id, h.hotel_id, h.city_id
FROM Hotel h INNER JOIN Room r ON
  h.hotel_id = r.hotel_id
WHERE (
   select count(*) from Room as rt
   where r.hotel_id = rt.hotel_id and r.price > rt.price
) <= 10;
ORDER BY h.city_id,h.hotel_id,r.price
```

as you can see you make an subquery to select the count of all rooms 
that have a price that is lower than the current root and see if 
the count is less than or equal to 10.

Observe in particular how i changed the

```
f.price < fruits.price
```

to

```
r.price > rt.price
```

because in the example of Xaprb he selects the N cheapest fruits

Hope that helps.

BTW Stackoverflow isn't for solving homework. You should learn something your self as well ;-)

Comment: It's ok to ask about homework: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-to-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: +1 for working through a solution using a similar problem to demonstrate the technique.

Comment: try using query from post http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/ by can't adapt it 
in semle above if tow or more fruit have some price, number of result row not equal 3, increases in the number of price matches

Comment: sample with mysql user vars not sorting result correctly.
`set @num := 0, @type := '';
select *
from (
   select r.room_price1 pr, r.room_id, h.hotel_name, c.city_name,
      @num := if(@type = city_id, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
      @type := city_id as dummy
  from Hotel h
  JOIN Room r USING(hotel_id)
  INNER JOIN City c USING(city_id)
  order by city_name, r.room_price1 asc
) as x where x.row_number <=4;`
minimal price for some hotel selected only if row_number > 6

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the table `Room` has a reference to the `Hotel` it belongs to

```
SELECT price, room_id, hotel_id, city_id
    FROM Hotel,Room 
    WHERE Hotel.hotel_id = Room.hotel_id
ORDER BY price GROUP BY city_id
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to meet the "for each city" requirement.

Comment: Worth noting, especially if this is indeed homework related, that even though the question is tagged for MySQL that the "Limit 10" clause is MySQL dialect specific. Other SQL dialects have different command clauses. For example, T-SQL used by MS SQL Server would use "SELECT TOP 10 price..." instead.